# how does a VBO get attached to a VAO

Tags: opengl, vertex-array-object, vertex-buffer-objects

VAO being Vertex Array Object and VBO being Vertex Buffer Object. The calls for creating and binding/unbinding VAOs and VBOs have a general format as given below:

```
GLuint VAO, VBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                            sizeof(GLfloat)* 9,
                            vertices,
                            GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                    3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                    0, 0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I've followed some tutorials on the internet, and they say that the VBO is bound to the VAO, but in the above code, I don't get how the "connection" or "binding" is established between the VBO and the VAO? I mean how do we know which VBO is bound to which VAO and what if a VBO is to be bound to multiple VAOs?

So, the basic question is: what does VBO is bound to VAO mean, how do we know which VBO is bound to which VAO and how is this binding established?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> how does a VBO get attached to a VAO

It is attached when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called.

Each attribute which is stated in the [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) state vector may refer to a different [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object). This reference is stored when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called. 
Then the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the attribute and the name (value) of the object is stored in the state vector of the VAO. The `ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is a global state.

This behaves different to the [Index Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`). The index buffer binding is stated within the Vertex Array Object. When a buffer is bound to the target `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then this buffer is associated to the vertex array object which is currently bound.

---

That means when you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);`, then a global state is set that stores `VBO`. `glVertexAttribPointer` retrieves `VBO` from the global state and assoicates it to `VAO`. 
When `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` is called again, then the previous binding is lost, but of course it does not change any state of the VAO.

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);              # bind VAO (global state)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1); # bind VBO1 (global state)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...);       # associate VBO1 to attribute 0 in VAO

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2); # bind VBO2 (change global state, VBO1 binding is lost)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...);       # associate VBO2 to attribute 1 in VAO
```

Comment: As far I understand with my poor technical literature capabilities:  when you call the `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);` , the buffer that bound to the target i.e. `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated with the currently active VAO? Did I correctly get this? And associating multiple VBO to a VAO is done by binding more VBO to the same target without unbinding the VAO? Did I get this part correctly as well ?

Comment: And this association is done with the code internal to `glVertexAttribPointer` ? Can you perhaps include a hint or pseudocode(if not the actual code) as to how this association is done? I mean it's really unsatisfying that the function signature does not contain either of the VAO or VBO but it somehow associates one with the other.

Comment: @juztcode No. When `glVertexAttribPointer` is called then the VBO is associated to the VAO. When `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)` is called the a global state is set.  `glVertexAttribPointer` gets the VBO from the global state and associates it to the VAO. I've add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: but if there is more than one call to glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO) with multiply generated VBO then are there multiple global states  or something?

Comment: @juztcode No, just the last one is stated. You have to bind the proper VBO before `glVertexAttribPointer`. The VAO can store one VBO for each attribute.

Comment: okay, so If I have a line of code containing `glBindBuffer(...); glBindBuffer(...); ` then the first buffer is lost since no call to `glVertexAttribPointer` was made?

Comment: okay, I finally got it thanks. But, the binding is lost, but the generated VBO isn't deleted right? How do we delete it?

Comment: @juztcode No it is not deleted. You have to call [`glDeleteBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml) explicitly, to delete a buffer object. OpenGL is a state engine. The global state just names the object which is used for operations (such as `glVertexAttribPointer`)